# Javascript Float value is considered NaN inside an array

Tags: javascript, error-handling, console, nan

This is a super weird error that's recently been thrown in my console. The actual array I'm logging and what it does is not important because the code still works fine when I avoid using it, but here it is:

[image: This is the odd error.]
Is there any reason the console might think these numbers are NaN? I'd certainly like to know.

Thanks!

Comment: What does iterating through the array and logging each individual value show? `NaN` or the numbers?

Comment: The Chrome console is notoriously weird about reporting on object/array values.

Comment: The array must be getting mutated (and getting `NaN`s inserted)